# Showing that $\vert\sin x\vert \geq \sin^2x $

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Can someone please explain these, in my textbook just mention it without any explanation
$$\vert \sin x\vert \geq \sin^2x  \tag1 $$
and for all $n>0$
$$\frac{1}{n}\geq 0 \tag2 $$ is this correct ? because $\frac{1}{n}$ can never be equal to zero it shouldn't be just $\frac{1}{n}>0 $ without equal sign?

Comment: $\sin x$ is between $[-1,1]$. So $|\sin x|$ is between $[0,1]$. So $|\sin x|^2$ (which is the same as $\sin ^2 x$), is less then $|\sin x|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardind the first inequality, just note that when $t\in [0,1]$, you have that $t^2 \leq t$. Substitute $t$ by $|\sin x|$ and you have the result.

Regarding the second inequality, you are correct when you say that $\frac 1n >0$, but $\frac{1}{n} \ge 0$ is also true.

Answer (score 0):

Because  $$|\sin{x}|-\sin^2x=|\sin{x}|(1-|\sin{x}|)\geq0$$
I hope now it's clear.